# Gradle ant.importBuild fails while importing and renaming ant target name

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am new to Gradle. I have an ANT build project that I am importing to Gradle using ant.importBuild in build.gradle.

This is a simple ant build.xml that I am using -

```
<project>
    <target name="hello">
        <echo>Hello, from Ant</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

A plain import works fine and I can run the hello target. Here is the contents of my build.gradle (that works) -

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml')
```

But, while importing, I want to rename the targets so they don't collide with the other tasks in my Gradle project. So, when I import the build.xml like this -

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml') { antTargetName ->
    'a' + antTargetName
}
```

it fails with this error -

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Git\appsec\archutil\gradle_migration\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle_migration'.
> Problem: failed to create task or type importBuild
  Cause: The name is undefined.
  Action: Check the spelling.
  Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
  Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I must be doing something silly wrong. What is it? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try a newer Gradle. I could repro with 2.0 but not 2.4. I think the ability to override ant target names may have been added in Gradle 2.2.